# Trying to rename an element in SQLite Database crashes the app

Tags: android, sqlite

I have an SQLite databse in my app which holds some data in it. I am trying to rename something inside the table and this is how I'm trying to do it:

```
public void renameName(String newName, String oldName){
    db.execSQL("UPDATE "+SQLiteHelper.MUSIC_TABLE_NAME+" SET "+SQLiteHelper.MUSIC_NAME+"='"+newName+"' WHERE "+SQLiteHelper.MUSIC_NAME+"='"+oldName+"'");
}
```

I'm calling this method like this:

```
Log.i("TAG", "Trying to rename "+element.getTitle()+" to "+renameTo);
db.renameName(renameTo, element.getTitle());
```

My app crashes when I call this. As you can see I call log.i to see if those variables are null but they are NOT (I get the null pointer exception).

Here's the logcat file:

```
03-03 17:50:39.329: E/AndroidRuntime(21154): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-03 17:50:39.329: E/AndroidRuntime(21154): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-03 17:50:39.329: E/AndroidRuntime(21154):    at com.matejhacin.beautifulvoicerecorder.database.DatabaseHandler.renameName(DatabaseHandler.java:63)
03-03 17:50:39.329: E/AndroidRuntime(21154):    at com.matejhacin.beautifulvoicerecorder.LibraryFragment$2.onClick(LibraryFragment.java:250)
03-03 17:50:39.329: E/AndroidRuntime(21154):    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:166)
03-03 17:50:39.329: E/AndroidRuntime(21154):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-03 17:50:39.329: E/AndroidRuntime(21154):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-03 17:50:39.329: E/AndroidRuntime(21154):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5289)
03-03 17:50:39.329: E/AndroidRuntime(21154):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-03 17:50:39.329: E/AndroidRuntime(21154):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-03 17:50:39.329: E/AndroidRuntime(21154):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
03-03 17:50:39.329: E/AndroidRuntime(21154):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
03-03 17:50:39.329: E/AndroidRuntime(21154):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Did you open the database before execSQL? I would guess db is null, not the strings.

Comment: Ughh I feel stupid...I completetly forgot to open the database. You can post an answer so that I can accept it :) thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your database first before using it, it's the database that is null and not the strings.
Happens :-)